# Yacc/lex ending too soon, EOF/grammar issue

Tags: bison, yacc, flex-lexer, eof

Btw I know it's not the best code to do what I did but whatever, not relevant to the issue.

I've a yacc/lex program but I can only enter one line and then it ends. I mean I start the program, I enter a line then press enter, the program works(showing the result, no issue), then I enter another line and press enter and it's not working anymore, and says "error", and the program ends.
Which is expected because the grammar rules doesn't expect this situation, for it, it should end at the \n.
But I don't know to fix it =/

In the y.file
http://pastie.org/10517954

In the l.file
http://pastie.org/10517955

I've tried to change the beginning of the grammmar with that, in order to make it end when I write END at the end. but it's not fixing it since result is not shown.

```
    S:
    e2 'E''N''D'
    ;
    e2 : e '\n' e2          {printf("Result : %d\n",$1);}
    |  e                {printf("Result : %d\n",$1);}
    ;
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Bison won't process that file, since you cannot just put `\n` in a bison rule. So in addition to pasting the actual grammar lines and enough of your scanner definition to be able to see what's going on, it would be useful to have a better problem description than "it's not working anymore." (Did it call in sick? Is it on strike? Or what?)

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation of the issue, I've corrected it and it should be better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bison/yacc create an implicit start rule of the form:

```
$start: start END
```

where `start` is your start non-terminal and `END` is a special token signifying the end of the file. (F)lex automatically generates END at the end of the file. So without you having to do anything, the tools will automatically require the input to be completely parsed.

Your problem is simply writing the correct repetition production.

In general, the regular language *A*<sup>*</sup> can be expressed as:

```
A':
  | A' A
```

And what you are looking for is ( *e* '\n' )<sup>*</sup>. So, following the above, a first approximation might be:

```
prog:
    | prog e '\n' { /* print $2 */ }
```

Personally, I would add one more rule, to allow blank lines to be ignored:

```
    | prog '\n'
```